# locking cam lever

Tags: mechanisms

Can anyone suggest an intuitive way of locking a cam lever such as this?

[image]

Comment: What is your definition of "intuitive"?

Comment: we have no idea what your intuition is telling you

Comment: your question is seeking an opinion ... not everybody will have the same intuition about the solution to the problem ... that makes your question off topic here

Answer (score 2):

Many methods come to mind:

1. bolt with a nut through the handle. (depends on what it is securing)
2. a C clip to hold the handle to a given surface.
3. a zip tie around the handle to some fixing or hole.

Answer (score 0):

On the backside of the stuff being clamped, add a spacer tube with a spring over it, then a washer and nylok nut. The handle over-centers and is held by the spring.

See PNs 11,53,58,57,16 in the IPB below.  The part description is in the link.

https://partscatalog.deere.com/jdrc/sidebyside/equipment/66671/referrer/navigation/pgId/407887826

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The European ball-hitch trailer coupler has a suitable mechanism.

[image]

*Image source: [Edwards Trailers UK](https://www.edwards-trailers.co.uk/trailer-parts/trailer-parts/couplings-spares/cast-trailer-coupling-50mm-heavy-duty-hitch/).*

- The fingers of the hand are inserted in the handle.
- The thumb presses at (1) to opens the safety catch releasing the handle at (3).
- The handle can now be moved up (2).

Comment: any such locking latches that thread on like this but smaller? actually a friction cinch on a smooth rod would be better, something like a caulk gun mechanism with locking engagement .. thinking alternatively one of those irwin 'quick grip' clamps with a lock

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic, I'm afraid. I don't know of any in any case.